# Request another user object in django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am currently faced with a challenge, when a user gets authenticated they can see objects posted by other users they are following. The challenge here is I want the authenticated user to click on the name of a user following them and it automatically takes then to the a page containing all the posts by that user they clicked on. So far my code keeps showing me just the posts by the authenticated user only.

```
#Views.py 

def article(request):

    return render(request, 'article.html', 
                  {'posts': post.objects.filter(user = request.user),'form' : CommentForm()})


#article.html
{% for post in posts %}

    <div class = "username">
    <font size="4.5">{{post.user}}</font>
    </div>

    <div class = "postbody">
    <p>{{ post.body|lower|truncatewords:50 }}</p>
    <p>{{post.likes}} people liked this article</a></p>
    </div>

    <p><a href="/posts/like/{{post.id}}" class="btn btn-default" role="button">likes {{post.likes}} </a></p>

{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I appreciate any help thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```
post.objects.filter(user = request.user)
```

to filter on some other user object most likely like this

```
post.objects.filter(user__pk=user_id)
```

For a more complete solution your `urls.py` should look like this

```
url(r'^article/(?P<user_id>)/$', views.article),
```

in your `views.py`, accept the `user_id` as a new parameter

```
def article(request, user_id):
    return render(request, 'article.html', 
              {'posts': post.objects.filter(user__pk=user_id),'form' : CommentForm()})
```